# Using Cygwin to build - Template with C Linkage

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cygwin

Im trying to build some of my plugins for Linux using Cygwin (keep screwing up Linux virtual machines so I decided to try setting up Cygwin since I wouldn't have to move all my SDKs and what not). Everything seemed okay except I got the error "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': No such file or directory" so I installed g++4.3 on top of gcc 4.3. Once I did that I am getting tons of errors now. The main ones that are being spammed are...

error: Template with C Linkage
error: Template with specialization with C Linkage

These are being spammed on files from the SDK that thousands of other people use to compile, so I know it isn't a 'dangling c extern' but I am assuming I am missing a package or something. In Ubuntu, installing build-essential fixes any of these problems, but I am at a loss with Cygwin. Any help would be much appreciated.

*Edit*

Here is an ampaste of the exact errors it is spewing http://www.ampaste.net/m3d0a864f

The first one from Sourcehook.h is because **linux** is apparently not defined in Cygwin, but the rest from the 'hl2sdk' have me at a loss.

Comment: Answering your parenthetical question: Use the MinTTY terminal (there's a Cygwin package for it); it's much friendlier than the standard Windows one.  Even in the Windows terminal, though, you can get a scrollback buffer -- click on the window icon to get the menu, select properties, and then there's a setting there for "screen buffer size".  Give that a really large height, and then you can scroll up that far.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compile that throws all these errors?  Some sample code would be useful here.

Comment: Thank you, MinTTY is much better than the standard Cygwin. Here is an paste of all my logs, it is basically just a small plugin, but this happens with anything I try to compile using this SDK. I ran into these issues on Ubuntu before too but build-essential fixed it. Im assuming some packages are off. http://www.ampaste.net/m3d0a864f

Comment: I was just told by one of the developers that the SDK doesn't compile with GCC 4.3 which is what I am using. Cygwin seems to not have 4.1 (the version they use) available though.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said there's no dangling **extern "C"**...  But why would that even be an issue given how you are **compiling with *gcc* and not *g++*???**  (Which will, in fact, happily treat *smsdk_ext.cpp* as a **C** and NOT **C++** file...  With all the errors and pain that come from doing so...)

---

Often you will see such error messages when the wrong include files are tagged **extern "C"**.  (Or not properly tagged as the case may be.)

Your error messages also indicate difficulty overloading functions...

```
platform.h: In function ‘double fsel(double, double, double)’:
platform.h:470: error: declaration of C function 'double fsel(double, double, double)'
conflicts with
platform.h:466: error: previous declaration 'float fsel(float, float, float)'
```

And problems with system (compiler) files.

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/signal.h:104,
            from /usr/include/signal.h:5,
            from /usr/include/pthread.h:15,
            from /cygdrive/...
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:74: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:97: error: ‘uid_t’ does not name a type

In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:5,
            from /usr/include/pthread.h:15,
            from /cygdrive/...
/usr/include/sys/signal.h:163: error: ‘pthread_t’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/sys/signal.h:163: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/usr/include/sys/signal.h:163: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
```

**So either your compiler installation is really munged OR...**

---

Alternatively, another approach is to start with a minimal *Hello World* program and see if that compiles.  Then build up, including what you need to, until you hit a problem.  (Or take the existing software and simplify it down until you find the problem area.  Start with one *"g++"* line, copy the file, and pare it down until the problem goes away.  Perhaps you have a *#define* or *typedef* that conflicts with something in a system file.)

Answer (score 0):

@Mr. Ree: "C ++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes .C, .cc, .cpp, .CPP, .c++, .cp, or .cxx; C ++ header files often use .hh, .hpp, .H, or (for shared template code) .tcc; and preprocessed C ++ files use the suffix .ii. **GCC recognizes files with these names and compiles them as C ++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name gcc)**." GCC stands for the GNU Compiler Collection for quite some time now. http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc